# LaTeX error in the LaTeX compilation while making pdf

Tags: pdftex, viewers, winedt

I am using Winedt for my latex related work. Till compilation its good, but when I click on acrobat reader of dvi2pdf, it opens the pdf file but also show the following thing :

[image]

whats the problem. can anybody help me in fixing it. thanks for help

Comment: If you use `sumatrapdf` as the viewer, you can live peacefully. Adobe is worst when it comes to tex related things.

Comment: I can't read what it says. Do you have a zoom in version?